# hibernate-entitymanager NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, glassfish-4.1

I'm deploying an `EAR` application built with Maven which has the following dependency in one of the modules:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to deploy the application in a **Glassfish Server 4.1** I get the following error:

```
Fatal:   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:149)
```

I made some research to solve this problem and made the following attempts:

#### First Attempt

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813782/hibernate-5-glassfish-4-1-1-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-lo) and used the script in [this article](https://agritsik.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/how-to-clear-glassfish-cache-helps-to-resolve-deployment-exception-inconsistent-module-state/) to clean the Glassfish's osgi-cache, as suggested in the question and in [this issue](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/554) of the Glassfish/Payara Github repository. Restarted the server. Same error.

#### Second Attempt

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595237/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-internal-coremessagelogger-debugflja) and tried the suggestion of the first answer, like this: looking at the dependency tree, I see that `hibernate-entitymanager` has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

So I searched at my Server installation and found the `jboss-logging.jar`. The installed version was `3.1.0-GA` (I'm not sure right now, but surely it was a previous version of the dependency). I downloaded `jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar` from the [Maven Central Repository](http://mvnrepository.com) and replaced the one in my Server installation. Restarted the server. Same error.

#### Third Attempt

Some comments in the previous post (and others) suggested to add a property `org.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j` as I'm using these dependencies for logging:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I found some `.properties` files in the `/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/` folder but none of them contains such a property and I don't know in which file to add that property. I also made some search in the Admin Console but I didn't found where to add properties. The only logging configuration I found was to configure logging levels.

After that I found where to put some JVM options for the Glassfish Server in the Admin Console and added `-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j` as an option but did not work for me (even more, I had to reboot my computer to get Glassfish in ground zero)

#### Fourth Attempt

Before all this I had a problem and made another question in StackOverflow. Guided by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738067/maven-ear-multimodule-project-not-packaging-persistence-xml?noredirect=1#comment62996463_37738067) in that post I changed the project configuration but nothing happened (I solved that problem with a little change in my dependencies, answer still pending)

After all the attempts, I'm running out of ideas and the problem remains. I don't know what could be the problem. Any guide, help or answer will be really appreciated. If anybody needs more details about the situation just let me know.

Thanks in advance for your collaboration.

---

## EDIT 1

I was searching and found [this article](https://medium.com/@mertcal/using-hibernate-5-on-payara-cc242212a5d6#.n1h21rmvm) which says something similar to what I did and adds a provided dependency for `jboss-logging` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But the error remains. Apparently it's something with the Server but I can't figure out what. I'm using **GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13)**

Answer (score 1):

I was using JBoss server 7.1 to deploy my project. In my case this error was due to the fact that the I was using jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar in my project but the JBoss 7 had a jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar (/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/jboss/logging/main/) by default. So, may be this was due to the jar conflict or method was not present in the jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar, I am not sure. But replacing the jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar with jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar and change mapping in module.xml (at the same above mentioned location) as follows

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.jboss.logging">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And the error was gone. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because GlassFish ships with an earlier version of JBoss Logging and this is being picked up by your application hence the NoSuchMethod error. The version of JBoss Logging shipped with GlassFish 4.1 does not have the method defined. You can try and replace the version of jboss-logging in the modules directory of glassfish this may or may not work but it looks like you tried and failed with this approach.

Another option is to upgrade to the latest Payara 4.1.1.162 which ships with JBoss Logging 3.3.0.Final.

Answer (score 0):

Block Glassfish for using its own lib when project lib is provided

Just create a `glassfish-web.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` directory. The contents of the file are shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
     <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This ensures that glassfish does not load it's internal libraries, but libraries from your project.